# Getting Data from API - PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I have been trying to connect to an API, which requires both a user and password key. I was able to connect using curl from the command line, however am having trouble using PHP.

I have tried using "user:password" as the AUTH key (which worked in curl), previously the code simply required a password and worked.
Below is the code that I am using:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "api-link-removed.com" . urlencode($location),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "accept: application/json",
        "authorization: Basic " . AUTH_KEY,
        "content-type: application/json"
    ),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
```

Any suggestions to what I might be doing wrong would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `user:password` needs to be base64 encoded, and _then_ passed as `authorization: basic …`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side Or you could just set the CURLOPT_USERNAME and CURLOPT_USERPWD options, and let cURL deal with the rest.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for your reply. So if I were to do the base64 route, I could simply replace AUTH_KEY with base64_encode(AUTH_KEY) and it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Guzzle HTTP

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('http://www.server.com/endpoint', [
    'auth' => [
        'username', 
        'password'
    ]
]);
```

https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll try it out. The option doesn't have the full parameter list though of above?

Comment: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
they are easy to use and well documented

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "your api url here",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "Name of api host: the name here",
            "Api key : api key here"
        ]
    );

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
```